# Layer control with group in openlayers

Tags: tree, controls, openlayers, layer

I'm creating a layer control with openlayers and following the example from http://ptsagkis.github.io/extjs_ol3_layercontrol/example1_withoptions.html. Is it possible to create a group within another group? Thanks

For example, we have the 'Tile Layers' group with two layers. I would like to create within this group, another group. Does anyone know if it's possible? Or, another component that makes it possible to assemble the layers control in tree form in openlayers v.5?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try ol-ext LayerSwiter control.
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/control/map.switcher.html

Comment: Thank you for always answering my questions. I'm already using LayerSwiter and it worked.